# SSSD Kerberos Authentication vs AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap, kerberos, sssd

I am trying to setup SSSD to authenticate to AD, and want to do in most secure way possible. I noticed when setting `auth_provider = ad`Port 389 is open. We have firewall rules in place that are blocking port 389. Setting `ldap_service_port = 636` did not do anything. Can someone explain what would be the difference between ad and krb5 auth provider? I currently have a conf for krb5, samba and sssd.

This is my current setup https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/wiki/Configuring_sssd_with_ad_server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To authenticate with AD, you will be using kerberos authentication regardless of using `ad` or `krb` as `auth_provider`.  By using `auth_provider = ad`, SSSD will handle everything for you, so you won't need to make specific kerberos or ldap configurations in your sssd.conf.

If you didn't use `realm join` as the document describes, I highly recommend it if possible in your scenario.  It will create your `sssd.conf` with the correct configurations, and it will create and install your kerberos key on your client.  You shouldn't need a `krb5.conf` or `smb.conf` (in my experience at least).  A couple tweaks may be required depending on your requirements.

Check the sssd-ad [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sssd-ad) for details on configuring the AD backend.

In regards to your question about ports, authentication is happening with Kerberos not LDAP/LDAPS (which is what uses ports 389 and 636).

Comment: I think the ID provider isnt secure though and is using LDAP. Can LDAPS be forced for the ID provider, since our firewall is blocking port 389. Authentication with kerberos is good and what we want, but dont want port 389 to be used. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you think it's secure, just because you are using LDAP/389?  Your passwords are only sent over the network during authentication which uses Kerberos which does not go over port 389.

Comment: That is just our current firewall setup. Will user and group names not still be sent over port 389?

Comment: Yes, but that shouldn't really be overly concerning.  If it is, you will want a combination of sssd-krb5 and sssd-ldap settings.  You will also need the proper certificates setup on your AD server and all of your clients to secure LDAP over port 636.

Answer (score 3):

id_provider=ad *is* secure enough because it uses GSSAPI bind using the Kerberos keytab. Try sniffing the LDAP traffic, you won't see anything. ldaps is also a non-standard extension, just stop using it :)

Comment: GSSAPI will encrypt the LDAP traffic sent on port 389?

Comment: yes. Same as StartTLS would do, there you also don't have to use port 636.